# Get the IOT hub connection string from Azure Device Provision Service

Tags: azure, azure-iot-hub, azure-iot-sdk

How can I get the IOT hub connection string in device using auto provisioning via Azure Device Provisioning Service. I am doing a group enrollment and that was a success but how can I get the assigned hub connection string to the device. I do get the hub name but not the connection string?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using both IoT Hub SDK and the Provisioning SDK, you do not need the hub connection string.  Take a look at our samples ([Java](https://github.com/Azure/azure-iot-sdk-java/blob/master/provisioning/provisioning-samples/provisioning-tpm-sample/src/main/java/samples/com/microsoft/azure/sdk/iot/ProvisioningTpmSample.java#L110), [Node](https://github.com/Azure/azure-iot-sdk-node/blob/master/provisioning/device/samples/register_tpm.js)) for how to use both together.

Comment: Would it be possible to explain why?